# How are the kernel builds at https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline monitored (if at all)?

Tags: kernel

How are the kernel builds at [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline) monitored? Can we be sure that the kernel builds staged there are successful?

If not, what should I do if I find a failed build? How can I know who to ask for more details or an explanation for failed builds?

Comment: why do you ask us users that? >:=D

Comment: @Rinzwind  https://kernel.ubuntu.com is a "service provided by Ubuntu and Canonical" which is a category [explicitly mentioned as on topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). While I would be in favor of changing our scope to make such things off topic, I fear that at the moment, they are on topic.

Comment: but this is something that then should be explained where kernel developers post info. The only legit answer would have to be made by an Ubuntu kernel developer. and I know none that are here.

Comment: @Rinzwind technically speaking it already exists.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds which says "these kernels are not supported".  Which explains that these kernels are not appropriate for regular use and have "no support" therefore any questions regarding that PPA are "these aren't supposed to be used for production what're you doing?" as a default answer for any questions related to it (see my answer)

Answer (score 4):

Based entirely on the wiki [here, maintained by the Kernel team about Mainline Builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds):

> By default, Ubuntu systems run with the Ubuntu kernels provided by the
> Ubuntu repositories. However i**t is handy to be able to test with unmodified upstream kernels to help locate problems in Ubuntu kernel patches, or to confirm that upstream has fixed a specific issue.** To
> this end we now offer select upstream kernel builds. **These kernels are
> made from unmodified kernel source but using the Ubuntu kernel
> configuration files.** These are then packaged as Ubuntu .deb files for
> simple installation, saving you the time of compiling kernels, and
> debugging build issues.
>
> ***These kernels are not supported and are not appropriate for production use.***

(emphasis mine)

... I would presume that **there is absolutely no support or monitoring of the Mainline kernels.**

As they're said, these mainline kernels are primarily useful to test unmodified upstream kernels to ID issues with patches or to confirm if upstream kernels have fixed a specific issue.  They are, however, not considered production-ready or compatible for production use, **nor** are they supported.

Given they say "not supported", that implies that mainline kernels are not 'monitored' or 'updated' in the PPA.

Comment: I agree with the not tested and no support statement. However, I disagree about the failed builds part, as there is an expectation from the users that the builds complete and the .deb file are published. I added a comment to [the kernel discourse page](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ask-us-anything-about-ubuntu-kernels/27664/80), where I see you posted earlier. Note that mainline PPA compile issues have historically not been an upstream issue, but local to the Ubuntu/Canonical compile method.

Comment: @DougSmythies given Ogra's statements that it's implied this is not supported or tested, that should also in part extend to the "There is no guarantee that a build and a /deb will be fine and complete when published, if you encounter issues with built kernels you should reach out to the kernel team in #ubuntu-kernel on IRC and let them know there's an issue" - otherwise the 'not supported' also implies 'not monitored' and unless they're told there's an issue nothing gets addressed/fixed